# Eclipse loop: reading history from git repository

Tags: eclipse, git

In Eclipse Progress section : I see "Reading history from Git Repository" again and again, forever and this is locking my account.

Could anyone tell me how to turn this off or update credentials in eclipse , eclipse would not do this loop.

Comment: In the _Progress_ view you can stop background tasks. What do you mean by "update credentials"? How could that help as Git is a distributed version-control system and the history is read from the local repository? Do you use the current version of EGit (which version exactly)?

Answer (score 3):

Just had this problem. To solve it just went the the "Git Respositories" view and checked out one of the local branches. It seems the problem was because no branch was checked out (according to Eclipse at least).

Answer (score 0):

In GitCmd, I have executed:

```
git gc --prune=now
```

Then, in Eclipse, I have recheckout my branch and the problem has disappeared. Unfortunately, the problem reappears progressively...